# Restore deleted Drupal index.php file

Tags: file, drupal, recover

Please note that I deleted the index.php file from one of my Drupal sites, I deleted it by mistake from Filezilla so it would be almost imposible to recover it. I know that I should be making backups and I do, unfortunately not for this new site.

I'm still having all the info in the database so my question is: is there anyway I can re-create my index.php file from the Drupal admin  with the the remaining info in my server? Probably this is a more than a silly question but I'm still a newbie with Drupal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just download the zip/tarball of the Drupal version you are using from Drupal.org:

https://drupal.org/download

Uncompress it locally, and then copy index.php up to your server.

Also, never ever do that again, and more importantly be more careful, because next time it might be a file you can't just easily replace.

Comment: Thank you very much Forest, I really appreciate it my friend, I was suffering to death due to this matter so I promise I'll be more careful. Have a great night!